# BigQuery not returning milliseconds part in timestamp

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

As per Google's docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions , using the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function returns the timestamp with milli/microsecond precision.

However, when I am using the same command on my Linux machine using bq I am not getting any precision in seconds. Any reason why is it so? Below is the result that I get:

```
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2019-10-27 20:20:53 |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit too long for a comment.

I'm pretty sure they are there.  You just don't seem them.  You can extract the milliseconds using `extract()`:

```
select extract(millisecond from current_timestamp)
```

999/1000 times this will be non-zero.

Comment: Yes, seems to be how `bq` represents timestamps because they are there in the temporary results table. As an alternative it can be cast to string: `bq query "SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS STRING) AS Now"`

Answer (score 1):

It is just how bq command line tool displays timestamp. You can see up to microseconds on web UI:
[image]

Comment: It appears BigQuery on Google Cloud Console for web now truncates just like command line.